# Xamarin : Android LinearLayout MouseDown like event

Tags: android, events, xamarin, mousedown, mouseup

I have tried searching available events for the LinearLayout layout for events that work the same way MouseDown and MouseUp events work in .NET (a.k.a. MouseDown = touch screen without releasing, MouseUp releasing finger from screen after a touch) but I can't find one.

Is this feature available for android systems?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that [`MotionEvent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) class describes all those events, specifically `MotionEventActions.Down` is the equivalent of `MouseDown` and  `MotionEventActions.Up` is for `MouseUp`.
But you should really go through some tutorials as these things are the basics that you need to know and understand.
For example [this one](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) explains on what input events are and which kinds are there.

Good Luck.